# DataBase authentication without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement a database authentication using custom UserDetails implementation. I have three roles, which are STUDENT, ADMIN and ADMINTRAINEE (these are enums) and some authorities provided for them , which I fetch from in-memory db (but I'm gonna switch to external one). This is web security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
private final ApplicationUserService userService;

@Autowired
public ApplicationSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,ApplicationUserService userService) {
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) 
throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "index", "/css/*", "/js/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(STUDENT.name())
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/courses", true)
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .usernameParameter("username")
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .tokenValiditySeconds((int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(21))
                .key("example")
                .rememberMeParameter("remember-me") 
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "remember-me")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login"); // custom address to redirect after logout
    return http.build();
}



// This is what I need to rewrite
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
 }

// Is used to utilize a custom impl of UserDetailsService
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
    return provider;
}
}
```

This is what the implementation of the UserDetailsService looks like:

```
@Service
public class ApplicationUserService implements UserDetailsService {

private final ApplicationUserDao applicationUserDao;

@Autowired
public ApplicationUserService(@Qualifier("fake") ApplicationUserDao applicationUserDao) {
    this.applicationUserDao = applicationUserDao;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return applicationUserDao
            .selectApplicationUserByUsername(username)
            .orElseThrow(() ->
                    new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("Username %s not found", username)));
}
}
```

So it calls the selectApplicationUserByUsername() method which is here:

```
public interface ApplicationUserDao {

Optional<ApplicationUser> selectApplicationUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

And this is the implementation of that interface:

```
@Repository("fake")
public class FakeApplicationUserDaoService implements 
ApplicationUserDao {

private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
public FakeApplicationUserDaoService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}

@Override
public Optional<ApplicationUser> selectApplicationUserByUsername(String username) {
    return getApplicationUsers().stream()
            .filter(applicationUser -> username.equals(applicationUser.getUsername()))
            .findFirst();
}

private List<ApplicationUser> getApplicationUsers() {
    List<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers = Lists.newArrayList(
            new ApplicationUser(
                    "annasmith",
                    passwordEncoder.encode("password"),
                    STUDENT.getGrantedAuthorities(),
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true
            ),
            new ApplicationUser(
                    "linda",
                    passwordEncoder.encode("password"),
                    ADMIN.getGrantedAuthorities(),
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true
            ),
            new ApplicationUser(
                    "tom",
                    passwordEncoder.encode("password"),
                    ADMINTRAINEE.getGrantedAuthorities(),
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true
            )
    );
    return applicationUsers;
}
}
```

And this is the ApplicationUser class which is a custom subsitute to the UserDetails default implementation class Spring Security uses:

```
public class ApplicationUser implements UserDetails {

private final Set<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities;
private final String password;
private final String username;
private final boolean isAccountNonExpired;
private final boolean isAccountNonLocked;
private final boolean isCredentialsNonExpired;
private final boolean isEnabled;

public ApplicationUser(String password,
                       String username,
                       Set<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities,
                       boolean isAccountNonExpired,
                       boolean isAccountNonLocked,
                       boolean isCredentialsNonExpired,
                       boolean isEnabled) {
    this.grantedAuthorities = grantedAuthorities;
    this.password = password;
    this.username = username;
    this.isAccountNonExpired = isAccountNonExpired;
    this.isAccountNonLocked = isAccountNonLocked;
    this.isCredentialsNonExpired = isCredentialsNonExpired;
    this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return grantedAuthorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return isAccountNonExpired;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return isAccountNonLocked;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return isCredentialsNonExpired;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return isEnabled;
}
}
```

So these are the enums for roles and authorities I wrote (the purpose of these is only for creating roles and the authorities users have; STUDENT does not have any authorities):

```
public enum ApplicationUserRole {
STUDENT(Sets.newHashSet()), // Sets is a class from the external library Guava
ADMIN(Sets.newHashSet(COURSE_READ,  COURSE_WRITE, STUDENT_READ, STUDENT_WRITE)),
ADMINTRAINEE(Sets.newHashSet(COURSE_READ, STUDENT_READ));

private final Set<ApplicationUserPermission> permissions;

ApplicationUserRole(Set<ApplicationUserPermission> permissions) {
    this.permissions = permissions;
}

public Set<ApplicationUserPermission> getPermissions() {
    return permissions;
}

public Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities() {
    Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> permissions = getPermissions().stream()
            .map(permission -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.getPermission()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    permissions.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + this.name()));
    return permissions;
}
}
```

This is the ApplicationUserPermission class:

```
public enum ApplicationUserPermission {
STUDENT_READ("student:read"),
STUDENT_WRITE("student:write"),
COURSE_READ("course:read"),
COURSE_WRITE("course:write");

private final String permission;

ApplicationUserPermission(String permission) {
    this.permission = permission;
}

public String getPermission() {
    return permission;
}
}
```

And PasswordConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class PasswordConfig {

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
}
}
```

The granted authorities then are used in a controller class for ADMIN and ADMINTRAINEE with the @PreAuthorize annotation.
So the problem I have is in ApplicationSecurityConfig. I don't know how to call the AuthenticationManangerBuilder to pass that daoAuthenticationProvider I have. In older versions of Spring Security, I could just override the configure method with AuthenticationManagerBuilder instance as an argument, but It's no longer the case since that abstract class is currently deprecated. So how do I rewrite the method? Or do I even have to do so? Pls any help is appreciated.

Comment: provide your entire configuration, its impossible to understand the context if all you provide is 2 small functions or you actually read the spring security documentation which tells you how to properly implement spring security

Comment: @Toerktumlare have a look. I just thought it would be a quick fix.

Comment: you have a LOT of strange things in your configuration. you have for instance `.loginPage("/login")` which means you have overridden the default olgin page and you are here telling psring security that you are going to provide a login page here? are you? You have also not posted any debug logs. Also your `configure` method is not needed. The ENTIRE POINT of having a dependency injection framework is that you should NOT be setting things manually like you are doing. If you define a `@Bean` the framework will automatically set the classes for you!

Comment: this is basic knowledge if you actually read the documentation for spring and spring security which you should have done before asking here. Also, where are your debug logs because i assume you have enabled debug logging and looked at them as they usually in 9 out of 10 cases will tell you what is wrong

Comment: @Toerktumlare I do this because of educational purposes, e.g. I want to understand how it works under the hood. What you have poined out I am clearly familiar with. These "strange things" like .loginPage("/login") is for my own understanding. I could redirect users to any other url and so on.

Comment: Then where are your logs then?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I am sorry. It turned out there was a very silly mistake on my end. It wasn't even about the Web Security Configuration. I didn't actually know that the order of credentials variables in ApplicationUser constructor WAS important. Because what I'd done before is I confused it, and when every time I was passing the username and password on login page, the username was the login and vice versa. Pretty annoying mistake as I autogenerated that constructor and did not even paid attention.

Comment: This is the reason why you should do proper debugging before asking on SO

Answer (score -1):

My mistake was about the order of credentials variables in ApplicationUser constructor.As it turned out it is very important.
What was the mistake:

```
public ApplicationUser(String password,
                   String username,
                   Set<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities,
                   boolean isAccountNonExpired,
                   boolean isAccountNonLocked,
                   boolean isCredentialsNonExpired,
                   boolean isEnabled) {
this.grantedAuthorities = grantedAuthorities;
this.password = password;
this.username = username;
this.isAccountNonExpired = isAccountNonExpired;
this.isAccountNonLocked = isAccountNonLocked;
this.isCredentialsNonExpired = isCredentialsNonExpired;
this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
```

}

How it should be written:

```
public ApplicationUser(String username,
                       String password,
                       Set<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities,
                       boolean isAccountNonExpired,
                       boolean isAccountNonLocked,
                       boolean isCredentialsNonExpired,
                       boolean isEnabled) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.grantedAuthorities = grantedAuthorities;
    this.isAccountNonExpired = isAccountNonExpired;
    this.isAccountNonLocked = isAccountNonLocked;
    this.isCredentialsNonExpired = isCredentialsNonExpired;
    this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
}
```

If you are using Spring Boot version with WebSecutiryConfigurerAdapter being deprecated, that configure method is not needed. You just build a securityFilterChain with the first method, and then provide password encoder and set userDetailsService for your db authentication.